# Knockout If-else condition inside html file in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.3, knockoutjs, html

I am customizing the shopping cart page, Here I worked `knockout js` and `html` code file. I successfully wrote `If` statement by below code.

```
<!-- ko if: isFreeShipping() -->
   //My Code goes here
<!-- /ko -->
```

For `else` statement not working, for these, I wrote below code.

```
    <!-- ko if: isFreeShipping() -->
       //My Code goes here
    <!-- ko ifnot: isFreeShipping() -->
       //My Code goes here
    <!-- /ko -->
```

> Error: Uncaught Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the
>   same element.

Can you please suggest me how to write `If Else` statement in html file?

Comment: i use same approch for my knockout code if else condtion it not binding for my ul tag which contain 2 li.It adding extra line of div html tags [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIgPV.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIgPV.png)

Comment: https://tagvibe.com/magento2/how-to-set-if-else-and-conditions-in-knockout-js-magento-2/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should write a below code for else condition

```
<!-- ko if: isFreeShipping() -->
    //My Code goes here
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko ifnot: isFreeShipping() -->
    //My Code goes here
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: Thankq. It's worked like charm!......

Comment: So the OP forgot the first `<!-- /ko -->`...

Answer (score 7):

Just to extend a bit on [Suresh Chikani](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/31609/suresh-chikani)'s answer to include more combinations under this question:

To do a if-elseif-else construction you would have in PHP:

```
if (A && B) {
    //...code
} elseif (A) { // And thus 'not B'
    //...code
} else { // Thus is 'not A' and 'not B'
    //...code
}
```

In Knockout you would do:

```
<!-- ko if: A && B -->
    //...code
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if: A && !B -->
    //...code
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if: !A && !B -->
    //...code
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: what about `if($value == "random value")`

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Maybe it is better to [ask a new question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) if this what you are saying is different from an `if-else` construction like the OP is asking about or an `if-elseif-else` construction I'm talking about.