# Magento 2 - How to use 'if...elseif...else' condition in knockout html?

Tags: knockoutjs, magento2.2.3

I want to add a condition `if...elseif...else` in a knockout HTML file.

I tried to add the condition like this,

```
<!-- ko if: condition 1 -->
    [...]
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko elseif: condition 2 -->
    [...]
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko else -->
    [...]
<!-- /ko -->
```

**I know how to add `if...elseif` and `if...notif`**. But I do not have the idea about this `if...elseif...else` condition.

Does anyone have the idea about this?

Comment: You can refer to this link may be it will be helpful for you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22775040/how-to-handle-if-else-statement-in-knockout-container-less-form

Comment: Not duplicate. Please see again question. **@SureshChikani**

Comment: It is duplicate. It's just a different combination of things. You can mimic `if A & B ... - elseif A ... - else ...` just by doing: `if A & B ... - if !A & B ... - if !A & !B ...` ;)

Comment: I actually just added that as an answer to the question "[Knockout If-else condition inside html file in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/216540/3326)"

Answer (score 0):

I have one alternative logic for you. Take one flag variable. with that you can do this easily.  **Below is not actual code but it shows the logic of alternative way for doing this.**

```
<!-- ko if: condition 1 -->
    [...](if this condition true make flag=true)
<!-- /ko -->

<!-- ko elseif: condition 2 -->
    [...](if this condition true make flag=true)
<!-- /ko -->

<!-- ko if: condition 3 --> (In condition 3 check if flag == false then do your stuff) 
    [...]
<!-- /ko -->
```

This one alternative solution or logic that you can implement to complete your requirement.

Comment: `var flag=false;` not possible in html file.

Answer (score 0):

There is no elseif. If you need else if you need to include other library see the [reference](https://github.com/brianmhunt/knockout-else)

You can use below workaround for if else

[image]